# Matplotlib cant find font metrics file even though I downloaded it manually

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, tex

So, I have seen a lot of questions about this, regarding rsfs fontfiles.

My error is the following :
`FileNotFoundError: missing font metrics file: cmss8`

even though I manually downloaded the file from [this](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm/tfm?lang=en) link, and created the required file (actually files cuz I tried it a dozen times).

Any help is appreciated since I spent almost half a day + to find solve this without results :)

Comment: Don't try to manually install fonts, let your tex distribution do this for you. Are you using texlive, miktex or something else?

Comment: texlive, i have no root access (server)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Note that when I try to run latex under cmd i get this "I can't find the format file `latex.fmt'!"

Comment: This sounds like a seriously broken latex installation. Maybe talk to whoever has access to this server or have a look at portable texlive installations which you could do at a place you have access to.

Comment: Isn't there a way to install it without using  root? (i tried anaconda and pip but yeah..)

Comment: You can get texlive from http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html and install in any location you have access to. No root required

Comment: but the the conda environment will be able to see it exists there?

Comment: Just set the paths as described in the link and everything will see it wherever you place it.